# Why MySQL query is faster the second time I run it?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a very strange question coming from a observation I just made, that might actually help me understand better my database behaviour and design it better .

First of all, this is a MySQL database we are talking about. There is an index on User_ID field.

Here is the code I run :

```
query3 =("SELECT Content FROM Twit "
          "WHERE User_ID = %s "
          "limit 25 ")

for userid, c_word in user22_list:
    cursorSQL.execute(query3, (userid,))
```

For some reason that I don't understand when I run it for the 200 fisrt users for example, then stop it, it would take arround 1sec per 10 users, pretty slow.

**But** if few minutes later I run it for the 1000 first user, it'll reach 200 in less than a sec, then slow down to the 10user/sec speed after that, and so on if I run it for 5000 after that (very fast until 1000, slow after that).

Questions:

- Could the query be temporarily stored somewhere (in my server's RAM?) explaining its speed?
- Do you see any ways to speed up the process ?

*****  Edit1 : 
As requested :

**The output of** `SHOW CREATE TABLE Twit`

> ```
>  Table    Create Table    
>     Twit  CREATE TABLE `Twit` (
>      `ID_num` bigint(45) NOT NULL,
>      `Content` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>      `User_ID` bigint(24) NOT NULL,
>      `Location` varchar(70) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>      `Date_create` datetime NOT NULL,
>      `Retweet_count` int(7) NOT NULL,
>      `isRetweet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>      `hasReetweet` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
>      `Original` bigint(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>      `Url` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>      `Favorite_count` int(7) NOT NULL,
>      PRIMARY KEY (`ID_num`),
>      KEY `User_ID` (`User_ID`),
>      KEY `Date_create` (`Date_create`),
>      KEY `User_ID_2` (`User_ID`)
>     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
> ```

**The Output of**  `EXPLAIN SELECT Content From...`

- id = 1
- select_type = 'SIMPLE'
- "table" = 'Twit'
- partitions = null
- type = 'ref'
- possible_keys = 'User_ID,User_ID_2'
- "key" = 'User_ID'
- key_len = '8'
- ref = 'const'
- "rows" = 298
- filtered = 100
- Extra = 'Using index condition';

Variables:

- `'innodb_buffer_pool_size', Value = '4294967296';`

To make it clearer I am calling the SELECT request in a python loop. Every iteration is very fast if I have already ran the SELECT request for this user, very slow otherwise. Doesn't matter if the RAM has be wiped (server reboot) or not.

Thanks.

Comment: [Should I blame caching, yes!](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/) `:)`

Comment: Damnit, that's what I didn't want to hear!!! means no optimization possible then ? thanks though

Comment: Actually this one looks like a built-in optimisation feature. LoL.

Comment: The query isn't stored exactly, but the database's **execution plan** is stored, and so is some (or all) of the data that was fetched during the first execution.  This is by design - the buffer cache (in RAM, used by the db process) is one of the most important elements used to boost overall performance of most modern databases.

Comment: caching would be the reason

Comment: I'm not sure I understand @maraca's answer. Could you detail it a bit more please? Thanks for the others, very clear.

Comment: @ylnor I basically tried to say almost the same thing as SlimsGhost, but he formulated it better. The point is that even if no data is cached, only the execution plan, then the 2nd time the query will still be faster, because the time it takes to optimize the query and get the execution plan is saved (well you need a more complex query to verify this, optimization can take quite some time).

Comment: Alright, got it. So that means there is no way to "hard-store" the optimization, or optimize in any other way?

Comment: Many programming languages and databases support the preprocessing of queries and binding of variables, which is not only much safer (against SQL injection) but can also be faster if the DBMS supports preprocessing of statements.

Comment: And of course you can always optimize the query yourself, you can't always count on the optimizer. Here you want to have the first result set as small as possible so when the next table is joined fewer rows have to be processed... same for filters (where clause) the most restrictive first (in oracle last).

Comment: Can't you process all users with `WHERE User_Id IN (...)` instead of using a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two "caches" that may explain the timing "speedup".

- InnoDB uses its "buffer pool" to avoid reloading stuff from disk.
- If the "Query cache" is on, then the second run could return "instantly" because the QC caches the result set.

"then slow down to the 10user/sec speed after that" -- smells like the data is not yet cached.

Don't use a `LIMIT` without an `ORDER BY`, unless you don't care which rows you get back.

What is `cursorSQL`?  Different clients do things differently; it may be important to understand what language you are using.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE Twit` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` so we can get into more details.

Please explain what you mean by "run it for the 1000 first user".  Is that 1000 selects?  One select with LIMIT 1000?  Something else?

How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
- I don't clearly understand what is meant by "cached". Is it only RAM cached, or can it be "hard-cached" too. Because the previous observation applies whether I just ran the query before Or if I just rebooted the server (and cleared the RAM...). 
- cursorSQL comes from the python-mysqlconnector I am using. calling SQL queries in python

I updated my post to provide the answers to your questions.

Thanks again!

Comment: To make it clear I am calling the SELECT request in a python loop. Every iteration is very fast if I have already ran the SELECT request for this user, very slow otherwise. Doesn't matter if the RAM has be wiped (server reboot) or not. I also  know this is not optimial and that it could be called in a single query instead of the loop.